# Is Tefillin worn during the Three Weeks of Tammuz?

Tags: tefilin, tisha-bav, chol-hamoed, selichot

BS''D

The Three Weeks are 3 weeks in Tammuz leading up to Tisha B'Av. During those weeks we add Selichos to our morning and afternoon prayers. My question is this: do we wear tefillin during these weeks or not? Does these 3 weeks count as a "Chol HaMoed" or do we still wear tefillin because the fast days are of Rabbinic, not Biblical origin?

Comment: Why might you think that the Three Weeks would "count as a 'Chol HaMoed'"?

Comment: Why not wear _tefillin_ even if they _are_ like _chol hamoed_?

Comment: I'm not aware of any custom to say _selichos_ throughout the three weeks. They're not even said on _Tisha B'Av_

Comment: We say selichot on Shiva Asa B'Tammuz as we also do on other fasts but not Tisha B'Av when we recite Kinnot.

Answer (score 2):

They are called בין המצרים is Hebrew or "the Three Weeks" in English. They are partly in Tammuz and partly in Av, so calling them "the Three Weeks of Tammuz", seems to be incorrect.
I am not aware of any additional prayers being said during "the Three Weeks".
On a fast day we wear tefillin. Only on תשעה באב we do not wear tefillin in the morning because we are like an Avel or an Onan.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for your answer. Since none of us know you, none of us has any reason to take your word for your claims. Can you [edit] in sources for them?

Comment: Even on Tisha B'av we wear Tefillin. We just wear it by Mincha

Answer (score 1):

These practices may be minhagim according to some but there is a Torah requirement to don Tefillin so yes, you certainly should.

Although sometimes the Rabbis have temporarily suspended the performance of a positive mitzvah, this is usually due to an overriding negative commandment they are trying to protect. For example, the reason we do not blow Shofar on Rosh Hashanah when it falls on Shabbat.

They have not done so in this case with regards tefillin.

Even on Tisha B'Av we don tefillin, just that we wait until the afternoon to do so.

Comment: This answer is based on the incorrect assumption that something that is biblicaly mandated cannot be superseded by rabbinic instruction to abstain from it. The question being asked is whether it is indeed superseded.

Comment: Not by minhag. Rabbinic instruction based on a halachic issue like not blowing shofar on shabbat, and that goes back to mishnaic times.